# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException at java.util.AbstractList.remove(Unknown Source)

Tags: java, arrays, exception, collections

I have tried below code

```
String s[]={"1","2","3","4"};  
Collection c=Arrays.asList(s);  
System.out.println(c.remove("1") +"  remove flag");  

System.out.println(" collcetion "+c);
```

I was getting

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException  
at java.util.AbstractList.remove(Unknown Source)  
at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.remove(Unknown Source)  
at java.util.AbstractCollection.remove(Unknown Source)  
at test.main(test.java:26)
```

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Comment: hi guys, I am new in stackoverflow and don't know much functionality about this site. I found this issue while working and I just thought that this will be helpful to others. so added this question.

Comment: You should probably read the FAQ. This is not the place to post questions you know the answer of

Comment: @deepankar You can answer your question. SO do not write your answer in same question add below and accept it. This question will not remain as unanswered question

Comment: @Deepankar Sarkar, you answered your own question.

Comment: @Oskar Thanks for your suggestion but I have added this because I haven't found any question to help me in this issue and after knowing the solution, I am just trying to help others.

Comment: Yes, I know. But that is not how SO works :)

Comment: btw... thank you, this save me a lot of time ;-)

Comment: **I have solved this issue by myself.** Initially I was blank about the issue. But after some research I found that `Arrays.asList(s)` returns _unmodifiable collection_ and so it throws an [UnsupportedOperationException](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/UnsupportedOperationException.html).

We can solve this problem by creating a new collection with that list

    `Collection c= new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(s));`  
   
or  
   
    `Collection c= new HashSet(Arrays.asList(s));`

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Easy work around is just to pass in the List into an `ArrayList`'s constructor.

For example:

```
String valuesInArray[]={"1","2","3","4"};  
List modifiableList = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(valuesInArray));
System.out.println(modifiableList.remove("1") + "  remove flag");  
System.out.println(" collcetion "+ modifiableList);
```

Response:

> true  remove flag
>
> collcetion [2, 3, 4]

Comment: Given the `List.remove()` operation takes an index, I think that should be `modifiableList.remove(0)`.

Comment: Hey @NickMaynard, it works both with indexes: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove-int- and with values: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove-java.lang.Object-

Answer (score 31):

Slight correction: no, it's not an unmodifiable Collection. It just doesn't support adding and removing elements, because it is backed by the supplied array and arrays aren't resizeable. But it supports operations like [`list.set(index, element)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#set%28int%2C%20E%29)

Comment: @Michel most of the work is done by java.util.AbstractList, but all optional methods of that throw UnsupportedOperationException. Public implementations like ArrayList override these no-op methods, but the internal implementation `Collections$Arraylist` used by `Arrays.asList(...)` does not override the add method. (but it does override the set method mentioned above)

Answer (score 8):

I was having this problem, because I was also initializing my list with `Arrays.asList`:

```
List<String> names = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");
```

To solve the problem, I used `addAll` instead:

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
names.addAll(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c"));
```

This way you can edit the list, add new items or remove.

Answer (score 8):

The List returned by `Arrays.asList` method of `java.util.Arrays` class is a fixed-size list object which means that elements cannot be added to or removed from the list.

So functions like Adding or Removing cannot be operated on such kind of Lists.

The solution to adding or removing without getting `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException` is ->

```
List<String> strList= new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(strs));

//Then Add or Remove can be called on such List

newList.add("100");
newList.remove("100");
```

Answer (score 1):

A one liner fix is to declare your list like this:

```
List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(0,8,1,5,7,0));
```

Answer (score 0):

The following method

```java
private void printCollection() {
  List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3", "4"));

  System.out.println(strings.remove("1") + " remove flag");
  System.out.println("collection " + strings);
}
```

Will print

```
true remove flag
collection [2, 3, 4]
```

Note that `true` is the (successful) return value from `remove()`.