# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException at java.util.AbstractList.remove

Tags: java, list, unsupportedoperation

I am trying to remove an item of a `List`.

```
list.remove(key);
```

However, it throws an exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.AbstractList.remove(AbstractList.java:161)
    at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.remove(AbstractList.java:374)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.remove(AbstractCollection.java:293)
    at bean.Bean.deleteRow(Bean.java:46)
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: Start by investigating the whole stacktrace...

Comment: Yes, "serverError: class javax.faces.el.EvaluationException" sounds like you're just looking at the client-side error message, but `javax.faces.el.EvaluationException` is a Java exception, so you should read the server logs.

Comment: I tried to change the bean and its scope from cdi Named to ManagedBean but I still have the error

Comment: This has nothing to do with JSF. You'd have had exactly the same problem when running the very same Java code using a plain Java application class with a `main()` method. Including the entire Java EE web interface in a question about an exception of `java.lang.*` package originating from your own code is unnecessary. I have trimmed down the irrelevant noise from the question to make it better focused.

Comment: How is the list created? You're probably running into an issue like the one [described in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7399482/java-lang-unsupportedoperationexception-at-java-util-abstractlist-removeunknown).

Answer (score 5):

The issue was during **Arrays.asList()** used to initialize the list, by using **list.add(String)** i fixed the problem